# first Calculator GUI in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

hey guys I am having trouble with my subtraction button and my division button not working, not sure what i did wrong.. Let me know if you can guide me so I can correct my code! - Ben :)

```
enter code here   
package week07_Ben_Calculator;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
```

public class AdvancedCalculatorGUI implements ActionListener {

```
JFrame frame;
JPanel butPanel;
JTextField res;
JTextField res2;
int oper = 0;
int currentCalc;
double last;
int memory = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Invocation
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        // Override run
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Call constructor
            new AdvancedCalculatorGUI();
        }
    });

}

// Create GUI
public AdvancedCalculatorGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Calculator");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // New text field
    res = new JTextField();
    res.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    res.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(res, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    butPanel = new JPanel();
    // 2nd text field 
    res2 = new JTextField();
    res2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
    res2.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(res2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Create grid
    butPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 3));
    frame.add(butPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Add button
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        addButton(butPanel, String.valueOf(i));
    }
    //read button 
    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read");
    readButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            memory = Integer.parseInt(res.getText());
            res.setText("");
        }
    });

    //store button
    JButton storeButton = new JButton("Store");
```

storeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            res.setText(memory+"");
        }
    });

    // Add button +
    JButton additionButton = new JButton("+");
    //additionButton.setActionCommand("+");
    additionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

        oper = 1;
        res2.setText(res2.getText()+"+");}
    });
    operAct additionAction = new operAct(1);
    additionButton.addActionListener(additionAction);
    // Subtract button
    JButton subtractionButton = new JButton("-");
    subtractionButton.setActionCommand("-");
    subtractionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

    oper = 1;
    res2.setText(res2.getText()+"-");}
});

    operAct subtractionAction = new operAct(2);
    subtractionButton.addActionListener(subtractionAction);
    // Equal button
    JButton eqButton = new JButton("=");
    eqButton.setActionCommand("=");
    eqButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            System.out.println(oper);
            if (!res.getText().isEmpty()) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(res.getText());
                if (oper == 1) {
                    int value = currentCalc + number;
                    last = value;
                    res.setText(Integer.toString(value));
                    res2.setText(res2.getText()+ "=" + Integer.toString(value));
                } else if (oper == 2) {
                    int value = currentCalc - number;
                    last = value;
                    res.setText(Integer.toString(value));
                    res2.setText(res2.getText()+ "=" + Integer.toString(value));
                } else if (oper == 3) {
                    int value = currentCalc * number;
                    last = value;
                    res.setText(Integer.toString(value));
                    res2.setText(res2.getText()+ "=" + Integer.toString(value));
                } else if (oper == 4) {
                    if (number == 0)
                        res.setText("ERR");
                    double value = currentCalc / number;
                    last = value;
                    res.setText(Double.toString(value));
                    res2.setText(res2.getText()+ "=" + Double.toString(value));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // multiplication button
    JButton mulButton = new JButton("*");
    mulButton.setActionCommand("*");
    mulButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

        oper = 1;
        res2.setText(res2.getText()+"*");}
    });

    operAct mulAction = new operAct(3);
    mulButton.addActionListener(mulAction);
    // division button
    JButton divButton = new JButton("/");
    divButton.setActionCommand("/");
    divButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

        oper = 1;
        res2.setText(res2.getText()+"/");}
    });

    operAct divAction = new operAct(4);
    divButton.addActionListener(divAction);
    butPanel.add(additionButton);
    butPanel.add(subtractionButton);
    butPanel.add(eqButton);
    butPanel.add(mulButton);
    butPanel.add(divButton);
    butPanel.add(readButton);
    butPanel.add(storeButton);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void addButton(Container par, String nam) {
    JButton b = new JButton(nam);
    b.setActionCommand(nam);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    par.add(b);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    String act = ev.getActionCommand();
    res.setText(act);
    System.out.println(ev);
    res2.setText(res2.getText() + "" + act);
}

private class operAct implements ActionListener {
    private int opt;

    public operAct(int oper) {
        opt = oper;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        currentCalc = Integer.parseInt(res.getText());
        oper = opt;
        System.out.println(oper+" "+opt+" "+ currentCalc);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're using `oper` to tell what operation you pushed.  Where do you set this variable, and how?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it give wrong values? Does the program crash? Does it do addition instead?

Comment: To solve this issue you could start debugging your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a debuggers-for-hire service.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through your code; first I would suggest to make things simpler.

To make it simpler, first use `getText()` on the strings entry and then convert them into integers.

For both `Input TextFields`, distinctly save them in separate variables of respective data-types and then do whatever operations you need by defining their methods .

Instead of overriding the 'action performed method' every time, you can use the `getAction` Command. It will make your code more readable and you can find errors easier.